# xkbcomp doesn't update keymap for running xterms?

Tags: linux, x11, keyboard, xkb

When I use setxkbmap all programs use the new layout but when I change the keyboard layout with xkbcomp to my own only newly started programs are affected (using xkbcomp with a file with a default keyboard that was created by xkbcomp it works). Why is that and how can I use xkbcomp and still get the new layout in already running programs?